# Log out or Shutdown using Unity

Tags: unity, logout

I want to log out, restart, shutdown, or what else with Unity, pressing "Super" and typing "log out" or something. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use terminal for this as -

To shutdown

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

To reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

or

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

To log out

```
gnome-session-quit
```

or

```
gnome-session-save --force-logout
```

Comment: That's not what I want, but Thank You. I want to press "Super" and type "Log Out" for example.

Comment: I don't have `gnome-session-save` but maybe `gnome-session-quit` is the same?

Comment: However, trying to log out with `gnome-session-quit` leads to this error: ```** (gnome-session-quit:2764): WARNING **: Failed to call logout: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files```

Answer (score 2):

1. Logout Using <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
2. For *Reboot* type in the terminal: `sudo reboot now`
3. For *Shutdown* type in the terminal: `sudo shutdown now`